# Como pegar itens de um json em c#

Tags: c#, json, linq

Depois de quase 3 dias tentando implementar não tive sucesso. Tenho o seguinte json:

```
{ "code": 200,
 "data": [ 
 { "id": 1, "type": "charge", "custom_id": "1208", "status": { "current": "new", "previous": null }, "identifiers": { "charge_id": 542814 }, "created_at": "2018-12-03 11:15:24" }, 
 { "id": 2, "type": "charge", "custom_id": "1208", "status": { "current": "waiting", "previous": "new" }, "identifiers": { "charge_id": 542814 }, "created_at": "2018-12-03 11:15:28" } ] }
```

Meu objetivo é pegar o item "status". O seguinte código funciona bem:

```
dynamic stuff1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jo);
string Text = stuff1.data.status.current;
```

O código funciona para pegar o item da primeira linha, mas como faço para pegar o atributo "status" **sempre da ultima linha**, porque ela sempre irá crescer. Tentei usar o `.ToLast()` para pegar o último registro de "current" mas não estou tendo êxito.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A resposta do @António está muito bem feita, pois ele te passa uma forma de deserializar seu JSON e transformar em um objeto que você possa utilizar ao longo do fluxo do seu sistema.

Irei te dar uma resposta caso você precise apenas do atributo da última linha e não queira fazer mais nada com as outras informações, ou seja, se não precisar utilizar os outros dados você pode seguir a seguinte alternativa.

```
//Temos nosso JSON salvo nessa variável
string json = "{ \"code\": 200,\"data\": [{ \"id\": 1, \"type\": \"charge\", \"custom_id\": \"1208\", \"status\": { \"current\": \"new\", \"previous\": null }, \"identifiers\": { \"charge_id\": 542814 }, \"created_at\": \"2018-12-03 11:15:24\" },  { \"id\": 2, \"type\": \"charge\", \"custom_id\": \"1208\", \"status\": { \"current\": \"waiting\", \"previous\": \"new\" }, \"identifiers\": { \"charge_id\": 542814 }, \"created_at\": \"2018-12-03 11:15:28\" } ] }";

//Criamos nosso tipo anônimo apenas definindo as propriedades e seus tipos de dados que nos interessam
var anonymousType = new
{
    data = new[]
    {
        new
        {
            status = new
            {
                        current = ""
                    }
                }
            }
        };

// Pegamos o último elemento "data" e pegamos o valor do "current" caso ele exista.
var current = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, anonymousType)?.data?.LastOrDefault()?.status?.current;
```

Comment: Pedro obrigado pela resposta, a deserialização foi perfeita!

Comment: Por nada meu caro =)

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro tens de criar um objecto com a estrutura similiar ao json para o JsonConvert saber para onde mapear os objectos. Segundo esse JSON será algo do genero

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public IList<Data> Data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "custom_id")]
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }

    public Status Status { get; set; }

    public Identifiers Identifiers { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "created_at")]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public string Current { get; set; }
    public string Previous { get; set; }
}

public class Identifiers
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "charge_id")]
    public string ChargeId { get; set; }
}
```

Depois é só fazer a deserialização e ir buscar o ultimo resultado:

```
var json = @" string com o json";
var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
var lastData = res.Data.LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: Antonio, obrigado pela resposta, ele deu o seguinte erro: A melhor correspondência de método sobrecarregado 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SiglaAdministracao.Web.Consulta.RootObject>(string)' tem alguns argumentos inválidos

Comment: Mas eu entendi a logica que você forneceu, vou implementar aqui e ja te falo como foi.

Comment: A variável "string" é do tipo string e tem lá o json?